# A Problem of Positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

$A$ and $B$ are both real symmetric matrices, $AB$ and $A+B$ are both positive definite matrices (symmetric).
Is this proposition ture : $A$ and $B$ are both positive matrices.
If is, please prove it. Else give a counterexample ~
thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints.* If $A,B$ and $AB$ are real symmetric, $A$ and $B$ must commute. Hence they are simultaneously orthogonally diagonalisable and the problem reduces to the scalar case.

Alternatively, for every eigenpair $(\lambda,x)$ $B$, consider $x^T(AB)x$ and $x^T(A+B)x$.